# A function $f\colon E\to F$ between finite sets is injective iff it is surjective iff it is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i cant solve this exercise, if you can help or give me a lead. I would like to also say its not marked.

Let $f$ an application from $E$ to $F$, with $\#E=\#F=n$. Show that these propositions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective
2. $f$ is surjective
3. $f$ is bijective

Going from 2 to 3 is fairly simple, and from 3 to 1 is automatic but I can't go from 1 to 2.

Thank you, cordially, JF

Comment: It is a duplicate

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh yes i know how to write in latex i just didnt know how to do it here. Also its not like its an exercise that requires special symbols aside for the cardinal but thank you

Comment: @FedericoFallucca huh? Sorry i dont know what that is

Comment: $\rm\LaTeX$ should be used whenever you want to differentiate mathematical symbols from text ones. Yes, it takes you three more seconds to type, but it makes for a far more readable question that has a greater chance of getting answers. On that note, the title should also reflect the content of the question. Asking here we *know* that you're asking for help.

Comment: @AsafKaragila alright, next time :))

Comment: Or... This time. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila i didnt know that too, happy now xd ?

Comment: No. I'm not. Don't half-ass things, not here, not in general. Especially not in mathematics, that's how mistakes happen. Also, a tip for the future, try to understand a bit how a site works (especially a community-based site like this one) before jumping in. It's the equivalent of checking that there's water in the pool before you dive-in head first.